# PHP: How to convert 0777 (an octal) to a string?

Tags: php

I have an octal that I am using to set permissions on a directory.

```
$permissions = 0777;
mkdir($directory, $permissions, true)
```

And I want to compare it to a string

```
$expectedPermissions = '0777'; //must be a string
if ($expectedPermissions != $permissions) {
    //do something
}
```

What would be the best way to do this comparison?

Answer (score 6):

Why not, in your case, just compare the two numerical values ?

Like this :

```
if (0777 != $permissions) {
    //do something
}
```

Still, to convert a value to a string containing the octal representation of a number, you could use **[`sprintf`](http://fr.php.net/sprintf)**, and the **`o` type specifier**.

For example, the following portion of code :

```
var_dump(sprintf("%04o", 0777));
```

Will get you :

```
string(4) "0777"
```

Comment: I don't think that is what he is looking for. This is in regards to unix permissions. 0777 would equate to a+rwx

Answer (score 4):

Do it the other way round: convert the string to a number and compare the numbers:

```
if (intval($expectedPermissions, 8) != $permissions) { // 8 specifies octal base for conversion
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is:

```
if (0777 != $permissions)
```

PHP recognizes octal literals (as your assignment shows).

That said, you could also compare strings instead of integers with:

```
if ('0777' != "0" . sprintf("%o", $permissions))
```

Answer (score 2):

Check base_convert function.

octal string representation of a number

```
$str = base_convert((string) 00032432, 10, 8);
```

you can do the conversion with any type hex, octal ....

Answer (score 0):

Simply cast the integer like so:

```
if('0777' != (string)$permissions) { // do something }
```

There is also another way putting $permissions in double quotes will also make PHP recognise it as a string:

```
if('0777' != "$permissions") { // do something }
```

Comment: $permissions is not an integer, it's an octal

Comment: @andrew take a look at http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php and you will see that mkdir() expects an int

Answer (score -1):

Hm... Type casting?

```
if ((string)$permissions != '0777') {
//do something
}
```

I don't know will it affect on later. (LAWL I'm slowpoke)